# mysql error - table name throws undeclared variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to back up some records to a separate table in the same database using phpMyAdmin. Here's the query and the error it's throwing. Both tables do exist and are spelled correctly; I copied and pasted the table names directly from their structure page. Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

```
SELECT *
INTO `arrc_VoucherBAK`
FROM `arrc_Voucher`
WHERE ActivatedDT LIKE "2010-11-10%"
AND BalanceInit IS NOT NULL


MySQL said: Documentation
#1327 - Undeclared variable: arrc_VoucherBAK
```

Comment: Nope, either way - quotes or not - I get the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949653/select-into-and-undeclared-variable-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL does not support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) the SELECT ... INTO ... syntax.

Read more [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949653/select-into-and-undeclared-variable-error)..

Comment: Thank you! Too much switching between systems; I can't remember which supports what.