# Why this query is not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, phpmyadmin

I am trying to take table backup before making any change, following this link for the query http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp . However its not working and throwing error #1327 - Undeclared variable: default_table_backup_31_08_2012. Let me know why it is not working?

**phpMyAdmin :Version - 3.4.5.**

***NOTE**: However I find a method under phpmyadmin , GOTO->Operations and perform the copy but i want to know what actually the mistake in the query and kindly provide a solution in terms of query so that i can use it in general :)

My sql query-

```
SELECT *
INTO default_table_backup_31_08_2012
FROM default_table
```

Comment: @Habib i already mentioned this under my note..plz chk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented under [`SELECT INTO TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html):

> MySQL Server doesn't support the `SELECT ... INTO TABLE` Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing. See [Section 13.2.5.1, “`INSERT ... SELECT` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html). For example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
>     SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
>     FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html).

In your case, you probably want:

```
CREATE TABLE default_table_backup_31_08_2012 SELECT * FROM default_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql does not support select into. please see the link below. [SELECT INTO and "Undeclared variable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949653/select-into-and-undeclared-variable-error). 
You can create a table 
CREATE TABLE default_backup

than copy information

```
INSERT INTO default_backup
SELECT * FROM default;
```