# MySQL ERROR 1327 when doing a INTO FROM

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

What is the problem with this command.

```
SELECT *  INTO database2.table2 FROM database1.table1;
```

It returns this error:

> ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: database2

The goal is to transfer data in `table1` to `database2`.

Comment: mysql or sqlserver ?

Comment: Duplicate:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949653/select-into-and-undeclared-variable-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`select ... into` is for storing values in variables. See the [documenation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) for more details.
What you need is an `insert into .. select ..`

```
insert into database2.table2 (select * from database1.table1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:
`CREATE TABLE database2.table2 AS select * from database1.table1;`

MySQL probably does not support `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM` syntax.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 uses `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM` syntax. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: @Clomp This is for variables not for tables.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like that :

```
INSERT INTO newDatabase.table1 (Column1, Column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM oldDatabase.table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
 insert into database2.table2 
  select * from database1.table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If those two databases are not connected to each other, you should think about that first.

1. **Connect two databases**

   Use `Linked Server` for SQL Server. 
   To know about how to create a linked server, [**See this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144051/selecting-data-from-two-different-servers-in-sql-server/22342227#22342227).
2. **Then use the query:**

   ```
   insert into database2.table2 
       select * from database1.table1;
   ```

   The syntax is:

   ```
   INSERT INTO ToTableName 
       SELECT */ColNames FROM FromTableName
   ```