# Undeclared variable error while using sql into

Tags: mysql, sql

Please tell me that why am i getting error and what should i do to get result.

**Tables in my database**

```
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_practice |
+--------------------+
| employee           |
| employee_duplicate |
| employee_record    |
+--------------------+
```

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

**QUERY**

```
select *
into employee_duplicate
from employee;
```

ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: employee_duplicate

Comment: To format the table/code/error correctly, please add **4 leading** space to each line of the table. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT INTO and "Undeclared variable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949653/select-into-and-undeclared-variable-error)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690447/mysql-error-1327-when-doing-a-into-from

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you cannot set the entire row to a variable.  Perhaps you just want to return the column:

```
select employee_duplicate
from employee;
```

If you want to set a variable, you can do:

```
select @employee_duplicate := employee_duplicate
from employee;
```

Although you can use `into`, most people find the `:=` syntax simpler to follow and to write.

Comment: I do not want to set a variable .I wanna transfer data from one table to another table by using select......into statement.