# MySQL Copying tables

Tags: mysql

I have an empty template table called Table1. I want to copy this table multiple times so I can have Table2 Table3 Table4 and so on, including the fields.

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
INTO Table2
FROM Table1
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: Table2
```

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mytables.Table2' doesn't exist

Comment: CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1; might work better for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT INTO and "Undeclared variable" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949653/select-into-and-undeclared-variable-error)

Answer (score 1):

If table doesn't exist do:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1;
```

After table is created do:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Comment: edited to include create table syntax, if table doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Since you said Table1 is empty you can create an identical empty table called Table2 like this:

```
create table table2 like table1
```

If Table1 has data in it and you want to copy the data as well, then you can do this:

```
create table table2 as select * from table1
```